# I have an error when running my php files to get data from my mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 16

Here my sql query

```
$sql = 'SELECT BeginTime, ChargedDuration, AreaName, AccountID
        FROM cdr
        WHERE BeginTime LIKE '%2015-07-20%'
        GROUP BY AreaName';

$q = $conn->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe)
```

Comment: Your division by zero is inconsistent with the code you posted.  Please post the code which is doing the questionable division.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Call to a member function setFetchMode() on boolean

use for `$sql = "query"` double quotes if there are single quotes inside.

```
try {
  $sql = "SELECT BeginTime, ChargedDuration, AreaName, AccountID
    FROM cdr
    WHERE BeginTime LIKE '%2015-07-20%'
    GROUP BY AreaName";
  $q = $conn->query($sql);
  $result = $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
     echo $row['ID'] . "\t" . $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['whatever'] . "\n";
   }
}
  ....
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I am failing to see a difference in what you posted, vs the original question, except you assign the result of `$q->set...` to a variable, you seem to stil be making the exact same call.

Comment: @tontonlayxx : My answer helped you ?

Comment: @moskito-x yep...i about to start learning php-mysql btw thanks alots

Answer (score -1):

single Quotes issue... please escape single quote inside query or double quote instead

Here updated code

```
$sql = 'SELECT BeginTime, ChargedDuration, AreaName, AccountID
        FROM cdr
        WHERE BeginTime LIKE $sql = \'%2015-07-20%\'
        GROUP BY AreaName';

$q = $conn->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe)
```